# Multi level Gradle projects with relative configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

Is it possible to set up a project tree in gradle so each subtree builds independently?

In the example directory (project) structure:

```
A
+  B1
   +  C1
   +  C2
+  B2
   +  C4
   +  C5
```

You should be able to build B1 by itself (will build C1 and C2) as well as A (which will build all 7 projects)

**Problem 1: A ignores B1 configuration**

A/B1/setting.gradle:

```
include "C1", "C2"
```

in A, executing "gradle projects" command will show B1 but not C1 or C2.

**Problem 2: Relative dependencies**

If C1 depends on C2, the only way to specify this is absolute path. This means that it will work for either A or B1, but not for both:

```
project(':B1:C2') // works for B1 but not for A
or
project(':A:B1:C2') // works for A but not for B1
```

Is this directory structure possible, where I can build A, B1 and B2 separatelly?

Comment: are you using any IDE like Android Studio ?

Comment: I am using eclipse. It all easy there, all the source trees are included and everything compiles.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you can only have one settings.gradle in the root project and there are no ways of grouping hierarchical projects into subgroups.

You can have multiple levels in your settings.gradle though:

```
include "b1",
        "b1:c1",
        "b1:c2",
        "b2",
        "b2:c4",
        "b2:c5"
```

This will build all projects if you execute gradle in the root but it won't build just b1, c1, and c2 if you execute it in b1.

I'm not really sure what you want to accomplish here, but maybe task dependencies can fix what you're after:

b1/build.gradle:

```
tasks.jar.dependsOn += [
    project(":b1:c1").tasks.jar,
    project(":b1:c2").tasks.jar
]
```

Running the jar task:

```
$ gradle -p b1 jar
:b1:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:b1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:b1:classes UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c1:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c1:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c1:classes UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c1:jar
:b1:c2:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c2:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c2:classes UP-TO-DATE
:b1:c2:jar
:b1:jar

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 0.761 secs
```

Comment: Thanks. That will solve problem 1 for the most part, but problem 2 is still there (how to specify build dependencies between sub projects).

We have many independent modules that we import using source control (no artifacts repo), so we need to build them in different combinations. If you think of project A as an app, then there are a few other apps, each needs different combination of sub projects.

It looks like the only solution is to keep a flat directory structure of all the subprojects, so they are always relative to each other as siblings.

Comment: If you do as I've done above you can depend on other projects in other deep hierarchies - it requires you to have one root project with settings.gradle though. b2/c4/build.gradle: `dependencies { compile project(":b1:c1") }`. Should work

Comment: Another thing you might want to take a look at is setting up your own Artifactory or Nexus and publishing artifacts there so you can depend on them as any other Maven/Ivy artifact.

Comment: Thanks. Can C1 express dependency on C2?It should be done in a way that works with or without A on top.

Comment: Everything I've posted relies on A being present since it contains settings.gradle which includes all subprojects. There are no restrictions as to which project can depend on which other project as long as A is the root project. I suspect you're trying to do a setup where you include B1 and B2 from A as external repositories. In that case I don't think you'll be able to do it since the hierarchies will be different (i.e. :c1 if B1 is root as opposed to :b1:c1 if A is root). Maybe it's doable with relative paths, but I honestly have no idea if Gradle supports that.